# New to Javascript, getting "ReferenceError: "sheet" is not defined." Not much on it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

First question on here, but I've been scouring this site for the past couple of days.  I'm incredibly new at this as you can see by my google tutorial based script!

I have been tasked with setting up a script with a timed trigger to send emails out based upon information that is added to multiple sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.  I'm trying to get this to work with 3 different sheets in one Google Spreadsheet.

Thanks so much, this site has been a wealth of knowledge.

EDIT:  Thanks you you all I've gotten a bit further.  I am able to send email to all sheets, but only only the last sheet that I reference sends emails out in bulk, "Support Staff".  The first two sheets only send one email out at a time "Administrators" and "Teachers."  Hopefully there is a simple reason for this.  I'm sure my script is ugly as sin and redundant.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var startRow = 2;  
  var numRows = 1000;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName ('Administrators')
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; 
    var message = row[28];       
    var emailSent = row[29]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  
      var subject = "Tuition Reimbursement Status";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 30).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName ('Teachers')
     var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
     var data = dataRange.getValues();
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
     var row = data[i];
     var emailAddress = row[1]; 
     var message = row[28];       
     var emailSent = row[29]; 
     if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  
       var subject = "Tuition Reimbursement Status";
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
       sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 30).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName ('Support Staff')
     var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
     var data = dataRange.getValues();
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
     var row = data[i];
     var emailAddress = row[1]; 
     var message = row[28];       
     var emailSent = row[29]; 
     if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  
       var subject = "Tuition Reimbursement Status";
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
       sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 30).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);



      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it will be sheets or sheet

Comment: You have `sheets` defined but not `sheet` .  `sheets` is an array of values.  Therefore if you wanted one `sheet` out of `sheets` you'd need to select it based on it's index like `sheets[index]`

Comment: Wow, really fast comments, thanks everyone.  Yes, when I changed it to `var dataRange = sheets.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)` I'm met with a new error, "TypeError: Cannot find function getRange in object Administrator,Teachers,Support Staff. (line 8, file "Code")"   Looksl like I'm getting further along, thanks everyone!

Comment: @AlexSmyk that is because you need to pass it a sheet, not the sheets object.  You need to loop through each sheet first, and within that loop perform your `getRange()` method, along with the other for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this yet.  But ideally you need to call the sendEmails2() method for each sheet within your sheets object.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

var sheets = ['Administrator', 'Teachers', 'Support Staff'];



function sendEmails2(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var startRow = 2;  
  var numRows = 1000;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; 
    var message = row[28];       
    var emailSent = row[29];     
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  
      var subject = "Tuition Reimbursement Status";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 30).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);



      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}



for(i=0; i<sheets.length;i++){
     sendEmails2(sheets[i]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks again Nick.  I tried that out and couldn't get around the sheet.getrange without referencing each sheet individually.  I reposted my script to my original post.  It's working on all three sheets now except only the third sheet referenced is getting emails in bulk.  The other two sheets are only getting them one at a time for each time I run the script!  Any thoughts?  Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexSmyk  I've updated my code so that you no longer have to call each sheet individually.  Try the edited code above.  In regards to the bulk/one at a time issue I am not sure, I haven't used the library you are using before.

Comment: If I run it as is, I get an error asking me to define a sheetname on line 9.  If I fill in one sheet name, like `ss.getSheetByName('Administrators');` it works but only for  that one sheet.  If I add the other sheets in like: `ss.getSheetByName('Administrators', 'Teachers', 'Support Staff')` it gives and error of "Cannot find method getSheetByName(string,string).